# How to send Form Data and other Data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to send HTML form data using AJAX however I'm also trying to send other data along with the same AJAX POST call.

Is this possible?

```
    $('#HTMLConForm').on('submit', function (e) 
{

    e.preventDefault();        
    $.ajax({
        url: "***NewUserURL.com***",
        type: "POST",
        data:{ 
              'otherinfo': otherinfo,
              'form_data': new FormData(this),
             },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert('You Have Registered')
            /*window.location = "index.html";  */
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {


        }
    });        
});
```

Any help with be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the FormData object itself to `data`, don't wrap it in a simple object.

Use the FormData object's [`append` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to add additional data.

```
e.preventDefault();     
const formdata = new FormData(this);
formdata.append("otherinfo", otherinfo);  
$.ajax({
    url: "***NewUserURL.com***",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
```